# Recycle bin weird behavior

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

this morning my colleague called me to check his recycle bin, his recycle bin has many files and he does not know anything about the files and how they got into his recycle bin.

After small investigation, another colleague said that he delete those files but they didn't appear in his recycle bin.

To simplify it more, person x deletes the files and the files does not appear in his recycle bin. person y does not know about the files and does not even has access to those files finds the files inside his recycle bin.

good to mention that i have a file server where the users files are stored.

file server OS: Windows Server 2012
client OS (used by users): Windows 10

does anyone know what could be the possible cause of this problem?
if yes, how can i fix it and how can i prevent such issues.

thank you

Comment: Were these files deleted from a folder that has been redirected to the file server? Are the users logging in with unique user accounts or do they share logon accounts? Can you reproduce the behavior?

Comment: the files were deleted from a shared folder(it appears as a mapped drive)  and  each user has his own unique user account. and no i can't reproduce this behavior. but am afraid from this to happen in the future

Comment: What OS are the clients and server running? Please do not only respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.